# If a title is too long can the message say how many characters need to be removed?

Tags: feature-request, title, character-limit

After typing a title that is longer than 150 characters and the focus goes elsewhere, a bubble pops up saying "Title cannot be longer than 150 characters".

1. Can the message say how long the title is or how many characters need to be removed?
2. Can the message appear after the maximum numbers has been reached?

Maybe we should have a running count of characters left when the maximum is close, for example "10 characters left".

Comment: The message already appears when title loses focus, not only when you submit. If it's not, it's a bug.

Comment: @ShadowWizard thanks, fixed that.